# how to display an object in an array php?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

i'm trying to display an object stored in an array but i can't get it to work
here is what i have (that's what var_dump shows me)

```
array(5) { [0]=> string(10) "04/06/2015" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "7" [3]=> string(1) "2" [4]=> object(stdClass)#64 (1) { ["ESP_Name"]=> string(11) "something" } } 
array(5) { [0]=> string(10) "03/06/2015" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(1) "7" [3]=> string(1) "3" [4]=> object(stdClass)#64 (1) { ["ESP_Name"]=> string(11) "something else" }}
```

and i've managed to display the first 4 items but i can't display the one in the object

```
<?php 
 foreach ($resulba as $i => $valor) {
echo $valor[$i][0];
echo $valor[$i][1];
echo $valor[$i][2];
echo $valor[$i][3];
echo $valor???;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `json_decode($jsonstring, true)` with the last parameter set to true will not add `stdClass` objects into the data, but arrays with textual keys. This should make accessing the data easier.

Failing to anticipate that your source of the data was JSON, the access for the object is simple:

```
echo $valor[$i][4]; // this would be the object itself - cannot be printed
                    // but that first part is used for object access.
echo $valor[$i][4]->ESP_Name; // the only property of the object, a string
                    // properties of objects are accessed with "->" and the property name.
```